# Javascript preventing other javascript from working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new to javascript. The code below prevents some other javascript (http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js) from running in my app. If I remove the code below, the Morris charts render properly. The code below does what I want, but it stops the charts from showing. I am programming in Rails. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var str = $("#rule_rule_type").val().toLowerCase();
if (str=="complex") {
    $("#id_ttl").hide();
    $("#id_condition_2").show();
    $("#id_value_2").show();
}
else if (str=="correlation") {
    $("#id_ttl").show();
    $("#id_condition_2").show();
    $("#id_value_2").show();
}
else if (str=="simple") {
    $("#id_ttl").hide();
    $("#id_condition_2").hide();
    $("#id_value_2").hide();
}

$("#rule_log_type").change(function () {
    logtype = $("#rule_log_type :selected").text();
        switch (logtype)
        {
            case "Syslog":
                $("#rule_severity")
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end()
                    .append('<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Alert">Alert</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Critical">Critical</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Error">Error</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Warning">Warning</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Notice">Notice</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Information">Information</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Debug">Debug</option>');
                $("#rule_condition_1")
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end()
                    .append('<option value="Severity">Severity</option>');
                $("#id_condition_2").hide();
                $("#id_value_2").hide();
                break;
            case "Microsoft Windows":
                $("#rule_severity")
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end()
                    .append('<option value="Critical">Critical</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Warning">Warning</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Information">Information</option>');
                $("#rule_condition_1")
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end()
                    .append('<option value="Event ID">Event ID</option>')
                    .append('<option value="Instance ID">Instance ID</option>');
                $("#id_condition_2").show();
                $("#id_value_2").show();
                break;
        }
});

$("#rule_rule_type").change(function () {
    ruletype = $("#rule_rule_type :selected").text();
        switch (ruletype)
        {
            case "Complex":
                $("#id_ttl").hide();
                $("#id_condition_2").show();
                $("#id_value_2").show();
                break;
            case "Correlation":
                $("#id_ttl").show();
                $("#id_condition_2").show();
                $("#id_value_2").show();
                break;
            case "Simple":
                $("#id_ttl").hide();
                $("#id_condition_2").hide();
                $("#id_value_2").hide();
                break;
        }
});
```

});

Comment: check your console for error ... if any post it here..

Comment: The console in my browser says "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$("#rule_rule_type").val().toLowerCase')".

Comment: If you copied the error EXACTLY then you're missing () after `toLowerCase` so either you doctored your code here or I don't know

Comment: @Michael-Szyndel, you are misreading the error snippet. The object is what's in bracket. The closing bracket starts before the word evaluating and ends after toLowerCase. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just that the code is causing an error.

Try defining `logtype` and `ruletype`

Replace:

```
var str = $("#rule_rule_type").val().toLowerCase();
```

With:

```
var str = $("#rule_rule_type").val().toLowerCase(), 
    logtype, ruletype;
```

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, `$("#rule_rule_type")` isn't in the DOM.

First, verify that you're trying to target the correct `id` attribute, and that you haven't misspelled anything. Then, ensure you're operating on the jQuery object with the correct method. `val()` will return the current value of an HTML input. `html()` will retrieve the HTML from within open-close HTML tags.